# LiveCycle drop-down list reference another field in an If statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, livecycle

I have 2 drop-down lists, both of which offer the choice of **Other**. When **Other** is chosen, a text field ("Other") becomes visible. If a different option is chosen, the field is hidden. But I don't want the field hidden when the different option for list "Tool" is chosen, if list "Cut" is displaying **Other** (or vice-versa). Clearly I'm missing something here:

```
form1.RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Types.Tool::change - (JavaScript, client)

if(xfa.event.newText == "Other"){
    Other.presence = "visible";
}

else{
    if (Cut.caption == "Other"){
        Other.presence = "visible";
    }
    else{
        Other.presence = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to make your answer work, jasotastic, but there's a lot about scripting I don't understand. However, this has worked for me (checking "Specify Item Values" on the Binding tab, where the list choice 'Other' has a value of 4):

```
var othercut = Cut.rawValue

if(xfa.event.newText == "Other"){
    Other.presence = "visible";
}
else{
    if (othercut == 4){
        Other.presence =  "visible";
    }
    else{
        Other.presence = "hidden";
    }
}
```

This would be for the "Tool" dropdown; corresponding changes are made in the "Cut" dropdown.

I had tried going with logic operators before and got nowhere. I really do like the formula that works in the both cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "Other" textfield to show up only if BOTH options are other, then you need something like this in both drop down lists' exit event.

```
if(Tool.rawValue == "Other" && Cut.rawValue == "Other") Other.presence = visible;
else Other.presence = "hidden";
```

Using the exit event will work just as well as the "change" event as long as you have "Commit On: Select" chosen in the Object palette. That's the default option.

If you only want it visible if EITHER of the drop down lists shows "Other" then you want this code:

```
if(Tool.rawValue == "Other" || Cut.rawValue == "Other") Other.presence = visible;
else Other.presence = "hidden";
```